# PHP crash on IIS with typo3 + opcache

Tags: php, iis-7.5, typo3, opcache

we get occasional, irregular 500 errors from IIS 7.5 when running

- PHP 5.6.1 with opcache enabled
- typo3 6.2 LTS

The opache blacklist contains the typo3temp cache directory.

Error:

> HTTP-Fehler 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   C:\php-responsive-5-6\php-cgi.exe - FastCGI-Process unexpectedly aborted**

The problem is that php does not leave any logs about what is going on.
However error_log is enabled and php effectively logs to a file but only in this case, there are no logs.

`"display_errors", "display_startup_errors" are set to "On".`

Disabling the opcache makes the error disappear.

We know that running PHP on IIS might not be a common technology stack but in our project we can't avoid it.
We are no specialists in configuring PHP on Windows though.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Please check the webservers error log for more specific information. On a windows server, you might also want to search through the protocols recorded by Windows.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a bug in PHP, if the PHP-process crashes? The IIS-process runs fine, it seems. So maybe an update to PHP 5.6.2 (released yesterday) would help.